# How to transform genus zero curve to conic section?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, transformation, parametrization, birational-geometry

I have a curve of genus zero:

$$C: 2 x^5-4 x^3 y+x^2 y+2 x y^3+2 x y^2+y^5$$

or in homogenized form:

$$C': 2 x^5-4 x^3 y z+x^2 y z^2+2 x y^3 z+2 x y^2 z^2+y^5$$

**How to transform it to some conic section curve with rational substitutions $x\to f_1(u, v), y\to f_2(u, v)$?**

(or do you know Sagemath code that would do that?)

I computed singular points of the curve and also rational parametrization of the curve if that can be useful to find the transformation.

Singular points:
$$(-1:1:1), (0:0:1), (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}:-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}:1), (\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}:-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}:1)$$

Rational parametrization (in one parameter or in two parameters):
$$x\to -\frac{p (2 p+1)}{4 p^5+1}, y\to \frac{2 p^3 (2 p+1)}{4 p^5+1}$$
$$x\to -\frac{p q^3 (2 p+q)}{4 p^5+q^5}, y\to \frac{2 p^3 q (2 p+q)}{4 p^5+q^5}$$

Also some small rational points on the curve:

$$(0,0), (-1,1), (\frac{1}{3},-\frac{2}{3}), (-\frac{3}{5},\frac{6}{5}), (-\frac{8}{9},\frac{4}{9}), (-\frac{54}{53},\frac{48}{53}), (-\frac{96}{13},\frac{108}{13})$$

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example of a curve of degree `3` and genus `0` that I was able to transform to conic - specifically parabola (with forward and backward transformations):

$$y^2=x^3-x^2,\left(x\to \frac{v}{u^2},y\to \frac{v}{u^3}\right)\\
v=u^2+1,\left(u\to \frac{x}{y},v\to \frac{x^3}{y^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer does not give any details of how the transformation was found, so let me give an alternative answer. First, you have a parametrisation so you have a morphism $C \to \mathbb{P}^1$. Embedding $\mathbb{P}^1$ as a conic can be done in many ways (choose three generic homogeneous degree 2 polynomials in $k[x,y]$).

Let me then deal with the more interesting case: We have a genus $0$ curve $C \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ and we don't know whether or not it has a smooth rational point. The key point to note is that if $C/k$ is a genus $0$ curve, then (by Riemann-Roch) the complete linear system of the anti-canonical divisor $|-K_C|$ defines a degree $1$ rational map $C \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$.

I don't know how to make this algorithmic in SageMath, but Magma has very good canonical divisor functionality for curves:

````
P2<x,y,z> := ProjectiveSpace(Rationals(), 2);
f := 2*x^5 - 4*x^3*y*z + x^2*y*z^2 + 2*x*y^3*z + 2*x*y^2*z^2+ y^5;
C := Curve(P2, f);
K := CanonicalDivisor(C);
lin_sys := Basis(-K);
phi := map<C -> P2 | lin_sys>;
X := Image(phi);
phi := map<C -> X | lin_sys>;
assert IsInvertible(phi);

// print Inverse(phi); // access the inverse of phi

// In response to the comment below, here's how to make the 
// map nicer because we know a point
P1 := ProjectiveSpace(Rationals(), 1);
lin_sys_P := Basis(Divisor(C![1,-2,3]));
phi := map<C -> P1 | lin_sys_P>;
assert IsInvertible(phi);

// print Inverse(phi); // access the inverse of phi
```
````

Comment: I am not familiar with Magma. I used http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ to execute your code. `phi` seems to store transformations, but why they have to be so huge compared with my relatively simple ones? And also how to obtain reverse transformation in Magma? `phi` seems to store only one direction of transformation.

Comment: @azerbajdzan they don't have to be huge, it's just how the machinery has spit them out - I'm allowed to post-compose with any automorphism of the plane (i.e., any element of $PGL_3(\mathbb{Q})$ and still get a valid conic). Since the conic has a nice point, parametrising with respect to that will probably give a nicer map. Finding the inverse of $\phi$ is simple using the Groebner basis machinery in computer algebra (like Magma, but also many others). I've edited

Comment: Can similarly be transformed curve of genus `1` and degree greater than `3` to curve of degree `3` without knowing any rational point?

Comment: No, that is more subtle. When you prove that an elliptic curve is given by a Weiestrass equation you need to have access to the point (so you can embed by $| 6P |$). For example a quadric intersection in $\mathbb{P}^3$ without a point can never be written as a plane cubic curve over the same field.

Comment: Also computing `Inverse(phi);` does not provide any result. Seems to be computationally hard to evaluate.

Comment: Does the code run for you up to ```IsInvertible(phi);``` because when ```Inverse(phi);``` is called, the inverse is already known (that's done in the aforementioned). It works for me on the Magma calculator (it takes 0.240 seconds)

Comment: Acctually `IsInvertible(phi);` returns `False`. But as I said I use http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ I do not have proper Magma.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149048/discussion-between-mummy-the-turkey-and-azerbajdzan).

Comment: You declared `phi` twice. For the first `phi := map<C -> P2 | lin_sys>;` `IsInvertible(phi);` returned `False` for second `phi := map<C -> X | lin_sys>;` It returned the inverse. That is OK, I do not understand syntax of Magma. Thanks.

Comment: The first $\phi$ is just the map $\phi_1 : C \to \mathbb{P}^2$ it's not invertible because they have different dimensions. I needed that map to construct its image, which is then (by construction) birational to $C$. The second (call it $\phi_2$) is just $\phi_1$ but now taking values in the image of $\phi_1$, this should then be birational

Comment: For an equivalent SageMath code, see https://ask.sagemath.org/question/74034/

Answer (score 0):

$$2 x^5-4 x^3 y+x^2 y+2 x y^3+2 x y^2+y^5=0,\left(x\to -\frac{8 u v^3-u+4 v^3-2 v}{16 v^5-1},y\to \frac{2 v \left(8 u v^3-u+4 v^3-2 v\right)}{16 v^5-1}\right)\\v-u^2=0,\left(u\to \frac{-2 x^5+2 x^3 y-x y^3-y^5}{2 x \left(x^3+y^3\right)},v\to -\frac{y}{2 x}\right)$$